# Apache Camel: How do I use a substitution variable in <from uri=""> with the intent is to chang the endpoint value in the variable

Tags: routes, apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint

So what I want to do is to consume messages from and endpoint that is stored in a variable like TempVar (below) located in the "from:" section of the route.

(Normally I would just add a route for each "from" end-point but in this particular scenario I need all logic to be covered in a single route.)

I intend to change the value in the variable "TempVar" for every messages consumed done in the <.. Stuff ..> section, with the purpose of achieving a sort of load-balancer round-robin style for the "from:" section

Something like this:

```
<camelContext>
 .. ..
  <route>
    <from uri="{{TempVar}}:queue:MY.QUEUENAME?mapJmsMessage=True&amp;concurrentConsumers=1"/>
   
    <.. stuff ..>

    <to uri="file:/dev/?allowNullBody=true&amp;autoCreate=false&amp;fileExist=append&amp;fileName=null"/>
  </route>
  .. ..
</camelContext>
```

This route basically consumes available messages for a queue on a given endpoint and forwards them to "dev/null"

Instead of the "TempVar" solution I have tried calling directly for a value in custom created bean where I manipulate the value in the var (declared outside of the camel context) but this will throw:
"Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot consume from a bean endpoint"

PS! we are not using java code to write the route, we are using "blueprints"

Does anyone have a good suggestion for how to use a substitution variable in the "from:" (illustrated in the example above) or a different approach to the RR loadbalancer type logic for the "from:" section ?

Br Morragh

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic variables with toD:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <toD uri="${header.foo}"/>
</route>
```

[TO D](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/toD-eip.html)

Answer (score 0):

When the Camel Context starts, all the routes are constructed and started. This is a one-time process during startup.

That said, whatever way you find to define the `from` endpoint in a variable, it is **not possible to change that endpoint dynamically during runtime**.

This is because the constructed routes are kind of "static". When a route is constructed, the **`from` endpoint address is "baked in" as static value**, no matter if it was hard-coded or provided through a variable in the code.

When your dynamic value changes during runtime, the **route does not change** because it is no more linked to your variable.

When you want to change a route `from` endpoint, I think you have to **create a new route and destroy the old one**. I guess that this would be possible during runtime, but since you want to change it for every message, it feels somehow "wrong" to do this.